# Determine if is a soft delete in a event handler Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have this event handler:

```
protected static function boot() {
    parent::boot();

    static::deleting(function($user) { // before delete() method call this
        $user->comments()->delete();

    });
}
```

When I use `$user->forceDelete();` and `$user->delete();` this event is triggered and delete all comments. This is not ok because I want this event to be triggered only on `$user->forceDelete();`. In my case the other tables does not have soft delete implemented

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check for the `forceDeleting` property on the model. This will  be set (and true) if you're performing a `forceDelete`

```
static::deleting(function($user) { // before delete() method call this
    if ($user->forceDeleting) {
        $user->comments()->delete();
    }
});
```

Comment: For Laravel 5.4+ use `$user->isForceDeleting()` as the `forceDeleting` property now has protected visibility.

Answer (score 0):

In the model class (as example):

```
public static function boot() {
    
    parent::boot();
    
    static::created(function($item){
        Log::info("Model Created:".get_class($item)."-ID-".$item->id.'-by user: '.Auth::id());
    });
    
    static::updated(function($item){
        Log::info("Model Updated:".get_class($item)."-ID-".$item->id.'-by user: '.Auth::id());
    });
    
    static::deleted(function($item){
        Log::info("Model Soft Delete:".get_class($item)."-ID-".$item->id.'-by user: '.Auth::id());
    });

    static::forceDeleted(function($item){
        Log::info("Model Force Delete:".get_class($item)."-ID-".$item->id.'-by user: '.Auth::id());
    });
    
}
```

Comment: How to take request()->example value?